# Parsing the CSV data returned by Yahoo Finance API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv, yahoo-finance

I want to parse the data returned by Yahoo Finance API that is in CSV format. I want the output in `company name: stock price` format. I have downloaded the Yahoo API example, the code is below:

```
String[] symbols = new String[] {"INTC", "BABA", "TSLA", "AIR.PA", "YHOO"};
Map<String, Stock> stocks = YahooFinance.get(symbols);
```

output:

> INFO: Parsing CSV line: N/A,\"INTC\",\"USD\",N/A,N/A,N/A,\"INTC\",100,\"INTC\",N/A,N/A,\"INTC\",500,\"INTC\",32.35,\"INTC\",N/A,\"INTC\",\"4/23/2015\",\"4:00pm\",N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,32348700,N/A,N/A,31.61,34.01,\"INTC\",4736000000,\"INTC\",\"INTC\",N/A,\"INTC\",153.21B,\"INTC\",4730885000,\"INTC\",\"6/1/2015\",N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,2.16,0.59,2.40,N/A,1.82,2.78,2.77,11.77,55.87B,24.19B,34.95
>       Apr 24, 2015 6:14:56 PM yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest getResult

I want only the price of that company.

Comment: I would recommend using a csv parser api look at apache...

Comment: Sir i have tried the google finance api the code is                          String googleResponse = HttpUtil.URLtoString("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG");
  String token[] = StringUtil.split(googleResponse, "//"); 
   
  JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray(token[1]);
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); but i have got null pointer exception

Comment: I can't understand the CSV contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are showing is the logging of the API.

You have all the requested [Stock](http://yahoofinance-api.com/javadoc/yahoofinance/Stock.html) objects available in your `stocks` variable. If you want to print the price for each of them, you should do something like this:

```
String[] symbols = new String[] {"INTC", "BABA", "TSLA", "AIR.PA", "YHOO"};
Map<String, Stock> stocks = YahooFinance.get(symbols); 

for(Stock s : stocks.values()) {
    System.out.println(s.getName() + ": " + s.getQuote().getPrice());
}
```

Check out the [javadoc](http://yahoofinance-api.com/javadoc/yahoofinance/YahooFinance.html) to see which objects and methods are available in the API.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
import csv
import StringIO

raw_file = StringIO.StringIO("data1, data2, data3, ...")
reader = csv.reader(raw_file)
for FIELD1, FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4 in reader:
   print FIELD2
```